# what is the difference between export default and module.exports

Tags: node.js, express

In node.js when I export a function, what is the proper way to import it into another file?

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/

Name.js:

```
function Name(){}

module.exports = Name;
```

index.js:

```
const Name = require('./Name');
```

o

Name.js:

```
function Name(){}

export default Name;
```

index.js:

```
const Name = require('./Name');
```

What would be the correct way to do it? and applying the destructuring as it would be?

Answer (score 0):

Do the first one with module.exports. This is the node.js way to do it.

The second why is more of an ES6 / commonJS alternative.

Again do the first one.